# C# Directory create, File create

Tags: c#, directory

I'm using this code:

```
private void Maker_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string folder = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData);
        string specificFolder = Path.Combine(folder, "ListMaker");
        string specificFile = Path.Combine(specificFolder, "info.mrfl");
        string specificFile2 = Path.Combine(specificFolder, "check.mrfl");

        if (!Directory.Exists(specificFolder))
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(specificFolder);
        }

        else if (!File.Exists(specificFile))
        {
            File.Create(specificFile);
        }

        else if (!File.Exists(specificFile2))
        {
            File.Create(specificFile2);
        }

        else
        {
            FileStream fs = new FileStream(specificFolder + "\\check.mrfl", FileMode.Open);

            Byte readSingleByte = (Byte)fs.ReadByte();
            int a = readSingleByte;
            fs.Close();

            if (a == 01)
            {
                checkBox1.CheckState = CheckState.Checked;

                FileStream fs2 = new FileStream(specificFolder + "\\Info.mrfl", FileMode.Open);

                Byte[] ename = new Byte[20];
                Byte[] phone = new Byte[40];
                Byte[] email = new Byte[60];

                fs2.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

                fs2.Read(ename, 0, ename.Length);
                fs2.Read(phone, 0, phone.Length);
                fs2.Read(email, 0, email.Length);

                text_ename.Text = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(ename);
                text_phone.Text = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(phone);
                text_email.Text = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(email);

                fs2.Close();
            }

            else
            {
                checkBox1.CheckState = CheckState.Unchecked;
                text_ename.Text = "";
                text_phone.Text = "";
                text_email.Text = "";
            }
        }
```

Result:

[image]

Only 'ListMaker' folder was created.

For more information, I edited my post.
I want save one directory. And two file in it.
When checkbox is checked, Each file save specific binary value.

Thanks for help. sorry, I can't speak English.

Comment: Lose the `else` on each of the two `else if` statements. You want each of the three things to happen independently of one another.

Comment: You need to tell us precisely _what the program is supposed to do_, not what your _observations_ are.  Otherwise we are only assuming that you want all three things to occur

Comment: I'm edit my post. Add more information.Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The else's on your  `else if` cause your code to only run the first `if`, and stop after that.

You need something like:

```
if (!Directory.Exists(specificFolder)) {
   Directory.CreateDirectory(specificFolder);
}
if (!File.Exists(specificFile)) {
   File.Create(specificFile); 
}
if (!File.Exists(specificFile2)) {
   File.Create(specificFile2);
}
```

Then, you'll want to confirm that the file is created before doing whatever else you need to do.

```
if(File.Exists(specificFile)) {
    //do things
}
```

etc.

As a side note, you'll probably run into IOExceptions if you create and then try to edit the files (as I believe C# keeps the files you create open).

I'd recommend creating your files like `File.Create(specificFile).Close()`

Comment: Thanks it work! File.Create(specificFile).Close() < - is really good tip